# flutter textField Cursor misplaced in TextAlign.center or TextAlign.right

Tags: flutter

In `textField`, Cursor is misplaced when text align is `TextAlign.center` or `TextAlign.right` (`TextAlign.end`).

Please, see attach gif.

good.gif click -> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qppd.gif)

misplace.gif click -> [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kMlW.gif)

This has some conditions and results.

Conditions.

1. `textAlign` is `TextAlign.center` or `TextAlign.right` (`TextAlign.end`).
2. Cursor Must comes at the last of each line. (last of column)
3. Cursor Must NOT comes at the last of lines. (!last of row)

   ((TextAlign.center || TextAlign.right || TextAlign.end)
   && Cursor at the last of column
   && !Cursor at the last of row)

Results
Cursor places at exactly same as `textAlign.start` or `textAlign.left`. (It seems like texts are applied align option. But cursor is not.)

Is anyone can solve this problem? please help me.

Or is there any plugins can use android `editText` and swift `UiTextField`?
Flutter's align and some keyboard issues makes me crazy.

add:
My code has nothing special.
Can test in basic code.

like
`TextField( maxLines: null, textAlign: TextAlign.end );`

or
`TextField( maxLines: null, textAlign: TextAlign.center );`

Comment: Could you share your code? This looks like it's a flutter issue, you might want to create an issue in the Flutter github

Answer (score -1):

```dart
TextField(　　　　　　　　
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none),
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                this._keyword = value;
              },
              controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue(
                  text: '${this._keyword == null ? "" : this._keyword}',  

                  selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
                      affinity: TextAffinity.downstream,
                      offset: '${this._keyword}'.length)))),
            ),
```